# Why vector.tcc implement _M_fill_insert by __uninitialized_move_a?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, move, noexcept

In [gcc vector.tcc::_M_fill_insert function (line524)](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/vector.tcc), the implementation uses

1. case 1: `__uninitialized_move_a`(line562) for case of uninitialized but existing memory;
2. case 2: `__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a`(line580) for newly allocated memory.

I am wondering why `__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a` has not been used in case1: there is no guarantee that the copy constructor or move constructor is noexcept. If copy constructor failed, the original vector could be recovered; if move constructor throws exception, the original vector will be in a unclear state?

Comment: This is a question you should ask Jonathan Wakely.

Comment: Guess the idea is to prevent memory leak, not the vector state.